# The type ''a list' is not compatible with the type 'ReactElement'

Tags: reactjs, f#, fable-f#

I am trying generate multiple div from a list of strings.
Generating single div with string is working fine

```
div []
    [ "mytext" |> str ]
```

But following code showing an error when trying to generate by a list of string

> "The type ''a list' is not compatible with the type 'ReactElement'"

```
  div []
    [
      myList
        |> List.map(fun f ->
            div[]
            [f |> str])]
    ]
```

Comment: Please check [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to properly format your code in question.

Comment: Please share the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the extra `[]` after your first `div`.

In the following: `div [] [ "hello" |> str ]` you have 2 lists. The first is an empty list of properties, the second is a list of child elements - with one child element `"hello" > str`.

In your second example you have the same 2 lists, the first still empty, the second contains another list, so you have a list with a list of react elements.

You need to just pass a list of react elements on their own.

Consider the following:

```ml
let words = ["Hello"; "World"; ]

let mapWords = //ReactElement list
    words |> List.map (fun w -> div[] [w |> str])

div [] [ mapWords ]
|> mountById "elmish-app" //added for fable REPL
```

`[ mapWords ]` is a list with a list.

What you do when you already have a list of react elements is just pass them as the second parameter to `div`:

```ml
div [] mapWords
|> mountById "elmish-app"
```

Or if you don't feel like a separate function:

`div [] (words |> List.map (fun w -> div[] [w |> str]))`

You need the extra parentheses around the expression, so F# knows it is all one expression, which is why I generally prefer to use smaller functions, and they also help keep it cleaner.

Examples in the Fable Repl [here](https://fable.io/repl/#?code=LAKA9gDgpgdgBAMQIYCMA2UB0AlKSDGALqKBoXAO5gBOAJgM5wC8cA2gEQASUaaY7AbjjsA6jTS1BcALokQZOAFsAnmLqMmoONso0GcAD4A%20OABkAlvUKZFSCHAAUAMwCu8CnAC0J2uYBurNJsHsZwVtTSAJRyAPQxItRgMADmoHG%20fmxBrFTqhiYWVjZ2jq7uXj7%20gcH5YYQRkbIgaTEAgmj0YJSJKS0ZWWxKqnqMTS3Y5skAFsQg-dUqagyxMQDyMFAWG33%20Aw65%20qGF1rb2zm6UFXAZ1Tm14VHRIKGKYG6EAELKAJK0wjyKSxTTx2CDsUBAA&html=DwCwLgtgNgfAUAAlAUwIYBN4O0iyyoLhgAOAtMgI4CuAlgG4C8A5AMID2AdmMt2QCoBPEsmYIAxlx7cWPAB5gA9OGgBuCSFQAnAM75G1MADMyADmZYcwHeK20SYBDq3jGAIgD6HgBIB5AMr8XopQtABGOopaaOJgAHQkWuzo1LG0XHEQtJxxAFY6bjDAijZ2DpbY1rb2js6unj4BQR4h4ZHRqLFk6OwQCUkpaRlZOfmFxaU1FUihnADWCNFQ7jpgglDIOiDI%20G5E0UbuXn6BwaERiuI6kWHUUBComdlxVwUIitPAswtLK2sbWx2YD2IAOR0apxa50ir0UqCgUCeOVeew%20iCsq3WyGmigAVAhfJwoIIEJwduhkOgEEZ2FoELRJJwnKgICQNghcYp0dgXlJUNlkFoyDpaAAvTYIOJhKDscQLADe3Jw2HQtB0bNQggAXNSNnJVEqAL5K3ncflkoUi8U6SUMrgIRXK5VhTpzADmSWonHQZEkMq0OsEyAR7AA7ganTgHlo3dkdQAGBAAVhI%20qNSom-2xcGK2wwWGAYWSJPEUFQ13cqBI5EZBAFWkKGdV9Hp6HcwayWzIVZIe1L5Z07fuapA3er40UzfgxSL6EE0%20UkFgQA&css=Q).

Comment: Also, `array` comprehension: `div [] [ for w in words -> div [] [str w] ]`